# Объект с динамическими вложенными ключами

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
let arr = [
    ['one','apple','acid','Lorem1'],
    ['one','strawberry','sugar','Lorem2'],
    ['two','melon','water','Lorem3'],
    ['two','melon','sugar','Lorem4'],
    ['three','cow','meat','Lorem5'],
    ['three','peeg','meat','Lorem6']
];
```

Необходимо превратить это в следующий объект:

```
   let obj = {
        one:{
            apple:{
                acid:{
                    title:'Lorem1'
                }
            },
            strawberry:{
                sugar:{
                    title:'Lorem2'
                }
            }
        },
        two:{
            melon:{
                water:{
                    title:'Lorem3'
                },
                sugar:{
                    title:'Lorem4'
                }
            }
        },
        three:{
            cow:{
                meat:{
                    title:'Lorem5'
                }
            },
            peeg:{
                meat:{
                    title:'Lorem6'


     }
        }
    }
}
```

Я пытался сделать это следующим кодом:

```
for( row = 1; row<arr.length; row++ ) {
    obj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]={
        title:arr[3]
    };
}
```

Но т.к. заранее индексы не определены, он выдаёт ошибку undefined.

Помогите найти правильное решение, в голову приходят только костыли на ифах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
  ['one', 'apple', 'acid', 'Lorem1'],
  ['one', 'strawberry', 'sugar', 'Lorem2'],
  ['two', 'melon', 'water', 'Lorem3'],
  ['two', 'melon', 'sugar', 'Lorem4'],
  ['three', 'cow', 'meat', 'Lorem5'],
  ['three', 'peeg', 'meat', 'Lorem6']
];

let obj = arr.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  let last = obj;
  for (let i = 0; i < item.length - 1; i++) {
    if (!last[item[i]])
      last[item[i]] = {};
    last = last[item[i]];
  }
  last.title = item[item.length - 1];
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```